# Importing data into Couchbase Community Edition Server

Tags: couchbase

I have a JSON dataset which is to be imported to a Couchbase server in my local machine. I have Couchbase Community Edition (version 5.0.1) and I found that 'cbimport' command is not supported in the community edition. So, is there any alternative way to import data to the database? Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I believe cbdocloader ships with Community, have you tried that? https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/cli/cbdocloader-tool.html

Comment: @MatthewGroves Thank you. I will try it

Comment: When I try to import data using cbdocloader command it shows a message : " Errors occured during the view creation phase. See logs for details". I have no idea what is the reason. I am new to NoSQL db's. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post a small sample of the json, and I'll give it a try?

Comment: The problem  i think was that the dataset contained array of json objects. cbdocloader supports json files having only one json object. So, have to split large dataset into individual json files.